# Bind Data from JSON to ListView (Xamarin.Forms Cross Platform C#)

Tags: c#, json, listview, xamarin

Currently I am stuck on how to pass JSON data to a listview.

Background information: A software will regularly create a json file which is available through a webservice (example down below). This data shall be parsed into a listview where the user can see the processes.

The JSON looks like in the following example (can contain up to 30 processes)

```
{
  "file_timestamp”: "00:00:00 AM",
  "process": [{
      "id": "1",
      "fzg_nr": "0123",
      "fzg_kz": "KHSKDNJK",
      "timestamp": "03:53:25 AM"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "fzg_nr": "0124",
      "fzg_kz": "UFJSDK",
      "timestamp": "04:53:25 AM"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "fzg_nr": "0125",
      "fzg_kz": "KDFJKLD",
      "timestamp": "05:53:25 AM"
    }
  ]
}
```

and this is my C# code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace dfg
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class JsonParsingPage : ContentPage
    {
        public JsonParsingPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            GetJSON();
        }

        public async void GetJSON()
        {
            try
            {
                var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
                var response = await client.GetAsync("http://myinternaliis/xample.JSON");
                string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                RootObject rootObject = new RootObject();
                ListView listViewJson = new ListView();
                if (json != "")
                {
                    rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
                }
                listViewJson.ItemsSource = rootObject.processes;
                Content = listViewJson;
            }
            catch (InvalidCastException e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
            ProgressLoader.IsVisible = false;
        }

        public class Process
        {
            public string id { get; set; }
            public string fzg_nr { get; set; }
            public string fzg_kz { get; set; }
            public string timestamp { get; set; }
        }

        public class RootObject
        {
           public string file_timestamp { get; set; }
           public List<Process> processes { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

The XAML file just contains the progressloader.

I would really appreciate any help, tipps or references. Thanks in advance, paul

edit: my problem is, that the data isnt shown in the listview...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypygD.jpg

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/data-and-databinding/

Comment: 1-Post code, not images. 2-What's your problem? I see on the image how you pass the data to the ListView.

Comment: First of all: What have you tried? We cannot really tell from what you provided. What is the exact issue? And *please* do not insert code as screenshots. Paste it as formatted code. Please see [ask] and [mcve] on how to ask good questions.

Comment: i am really sorry guys, i had kind of trouble to get the code well formatted into this thread. now it should be fine.

Comment: Your json sample has a property called "process" while your rootobject class has a property called "processes"

Comment: @jason yes, because i thought i logically rather pass the list with all its elements into the listview ?! i am not sure about that. at least i am getting a long error when i do so.

Comment: Have you verified that your json is being deserialized correctly?  If the names do not match they probably are not.  You need to take the time to debug your code to be sure each step is working as expected, that will help narrow down the cause of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the replies so far. i could use the problem thanks to you guys!

here was the problem:

first of all @Mario C Simao Jr was right. i had to bind the data to the cells and i did it just like he suggested. the method changed to this:

```
public async void GetJSON()
        {
            try
            {
                var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
                var response = await client.GetAsync("http://x.x.x.x/xample.JSON");
                string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                RootObject rootObject = new RootObject();
                ListView listViewJson = new ListView();
                if (json != "")
                {
                    rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
                }
                DataTemplate template = new DataTemplate(typeof(TextCell));
                template.SetBinding(TextCell.TextProperty, "id");
                template.SetBinding(TextCell.DetailProperty, "fzg_kz");
                listViewJson.ItemTemplate = template;
                listViewJson.ItemsSource = rootObject.process;
                Content = listViewJson;
            }
            catch (InvalidCastException e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
            ProgressLoader.IsVisible = false;
        }
```

but the root of all problems was the `public class RootObject`. 
i had to change it to this:

```
public class RootObject
        {
           public string file_timestamp { get; set; }
           public List<Process> process { get; set; }
        }
```

so it was a classic layer 8 mistake of myself.

thank you so much for your help!

sincerely, paul

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is because your `ListView` doesn't have a `ItemTemplate` defined, so it don't know what information must be shown.

The screenshot linked demonstrates exactly this - you can view the "rows" in the `ListView`, but you can't view any data of this rows.

You can use the basic `DataTemplate` to show some properties of your parsed JSON object, like this:

```
DataTemplate template = new DataTemplate(typeof(TextCell));
template.SetBinding(TextCell.TextProperty, "id");
template.SetBinding(TextCell.DetailProperty, "fzg_kz");

listViewJson.ItemTemplate = template;
```

Comment: i changed the code but unfortunatedly it doesnt changed a thing. so there must be something wrong with my json dont you think? i am going to distinguish the error more specific.